# Why Navbar nested dropdown menu not working

Tags: javascript, dropdown, navbar

I downloaded a bootstrap template from web and i'm trying to create a nested dropdown menu nut it doesn't work. hen i click on 'Nuova Gallery' instead of dropdown, the menu close.
I'm new to javascript and bootstrap, please could you help me?

below the code and javascript

````
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html#page-top"><img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/navbar-logo.png" title="Logo" alt="Logo Premio Troisi" /></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    Menu
                    <i class="fas fa-bars ms-1"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">Chi Siamo</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Il Premio
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                
                                <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery_2023.html">Gallery 2023</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery_2022.html">Gallery 2022</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery_2021.html">Gallery 2021</a></li>
                                <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery_2020.html">Gallery 2020</a></li>
                                
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle faq" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Nuova Gallery
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery_2020.html">Conferenza Stampa</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery_2023.html">Serata 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery_2022.html">Serata 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery_2021.html">Serata 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery_2020.html">Serata 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="nav-link" href="gallery_2020.html">Serata 5</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" role="button" href="#portfolio">Bandi</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" role="button" href="press.html">Press</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" role="button" href="#contact">Contatti</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" role="button" href="tickets.html">Tickets</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
      ```
````

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {

```
// Navbar shrink function
var navbarShrink = function () {
    const navbarCollapsible = document.body.querySelector('#mainNav');
    if (!navbarCollapsible) {
        return;
    }
    if (window.scrollY === 0) {
        navbarCollapsible.classList.remove('navbar-shrink')
    } else {
        navbarCollapsible.classList.add('navbar-shrink')
    }

};

// Shrink the navbar 
navbarShrink();

// Shrink the navbar when page is scrolled
document.addEventListener('scroll', navbarShrink);

//  Activate Bootstrap scrollspy on the main nav element
const mainNav = document.body.querySelector('#mainNav');
if (mainNav) {
    new bootstrap.ScrollSpy(document.body, {
        target: '#mainNav',
        rootMargin: '0px 0px -40%',
    });
};

// Collapse responsive navbar when toggler is visible
const navbarToggler = document.body.querySelector('.navbar-toggler');
const responsiveNavItems = [].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('#navbarResponsive .nav-link')
);
responsiveNavItems.map(function (responsiveNavItem) {
    responsiveNavItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (window.getComputedStyle(navbarToggler).display !== 'none') {
            navbarToggler.click();
        }
    });
});
```

```
It's something that i need to change?
```